# how to access request payload on php server

Tags: php, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to send data from ionic to a php server. But the request, post and get are empty. I tried with postman and it works but if I send with http.post of ionic does not work. I tried using on php:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data, TRUE);
```

I have this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

exit(0);
}
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data, TRUE);

echo $data;

$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$username = htmlspecialchars($username, ENT_QUOTES);
$password = md5($password . PASSWORD_DEFAULT2);
```

but data is empty. In ionic i do:

```
let credentials = {username:user,password:pass};
let headers = new Headers();
this.http.post(this.serverUrl+'login.php',JSON.stringify(credentials),{headers: headers})
  .map(response =>{  return response.json()})
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
  ,error => console.log("loading error: ");
```

In the developer tools of chrome I can see the data y want to send.

Comment: if you want to be taken more seriously do not post code as images

Comment: I fix it. But thanks, next time i will do it